# How to apply and save Android camera effects in camera activity?

Tags: android, android-camera

Can I apply effects on a **running** camera surface and **save with** these effects onto the SD card?

I want to apply effects like negative, black & white, etc.

Comment: when you say "save with" do you mean you want to preserve the effects on the photo that you take?

Comment: @ Dr.Dredel Yes I Want To Save Captured Image With Effects On It..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the parameters to whatever you want like this...

```
            mCamera = Camera.open();
            Camera.Parameters cp = mCamera.getParameters();

            cp.setJpegQuality(100);
            cp.setColorEffect(Parameters.SCENE_MODE_PORTRAIT);
            cp.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
            cp.setColorEffect(Parameters.EFFECT_MONO);
            setPictureSize(cp);

            mCamera.setParameters(cp);
```

Then take your picture and the effects will be in the data byte array that's in the callback. Just save the image to the SDcard as is.

Comment: great... feel free to accept mine as the correct one :) and welcome to Stack Overflow.